# How to pass classname to a jquery function through varible

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html

I have a two variable `m` and `b` having `class` names,

```
m='box1'
b='box2'
```

I want to assign the values of `m` and `n` to jquery function so that it will work

i want it to be like  $('.box1') and  $('.box2')

I have done the below code but giving me error

which is the correct syntax for entering it?

```
$('.+m+').toggleClass('flip');
$('.+b+').toggleClass('flip');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass the variable inside `$()`.

```
var m = '.box1';
var b = '.box2';

$(m).toggleClass('flip');
$(b).toggleClass('flip');
```

If you want to add . seperately, you can concatenate it inside `$()`

```
var m = 'box1';
var b = 'box2';

$('.'+m).toggleClass('flip');
$('.'+b).toggleClass('flip');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate the variable like:

```
$('.'+m)
```

If you want to use both at once:

```
$('.'+m+', .'+n)
```

Or if you want to [add](http://api.jquery.com/add) later:

```
var m = $('.'+m);
m.add('.'+n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenation the class symbol and variable in the following way:

```
$('.' + m + ', .' + b).toggleClass('flip');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate like so:

```
$("." + m + ", ." + b).toggleClass("flip");
```

You could also use ES6 template literals:

```
$(`.${m}, .${b}`).toggleClass("flip"):
```